# Libssh2 - libssh2_scp_recv2 function

Tags: c++, libssh2

Can someone explain me the `libssh2_scp_recv2()` function from libssh2 lib?

According [to this](https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_scp_recv2.html) I need to input the session var (`LIBSSH2_SESSION *session`), the path to the file I want (`const char *path`) and a struct with information of the file I want (`struct_stat *sb`).

Where is the part I receive the data from that file? Because what return is a pointer to the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!
This function is only to make a request to that session and them it's just read it like a ssh output using the `libssh2_channel_read()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to use `libssh2_scp_recv2()` and `libssh2_channel_read()` in the file /example/scp.c

I replaced the `write(1, mem, rc)` there by `fwrite (mem, 1, amount, targetFile)` to write the buffer content to a file.